# Does Puppeteer support emulating WebAuthn authenticators in Chromium?

Tags: puppeteer, chromium

I intend to configure Puppeteer 21.x to emulate WebAuthn authenticators, as described here:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/webauthn/

The specifics of the scenario that is to be tested with puppeteer allow the end-user to register a FIDO2/WebAuthn capable device, and then use it later to authenticate and pass the validation step.

Puppeteer version is 21.x, and it's being used with the bundled Chromium. I did not find an example, reference or article that would allow one to do this, so the questions are:

1. Does Puppeteer support the ability to configure and emulate WebAuthn authenticators in Chromium?
2. ...and if it does, is there documentation and/or examples that would explain how one might do so?

Thank you!